# Ajax for nested model with CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have been referring to this awesome tutorial from Railscast on [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast). Everything works great. However, I noticed that I needed the Ajax functionality for all add/remove.

I have a 3-level nested models. `Country`, `States`, `Shops`. For example:

```
United States
|__ California
    |__ Shop A
    |__ Shop B
    |__ (Add new shop)
|__ New York
    |__ Shop C
    |__ Shop D
    |__ (Add new shop)
(Add new state)
```

I have read and googled all tutorials available, but nothing seems to fit my purpose. They mostly offer the way to add/remove items dynamically, but without interacting to server. I want that once the link `Add...` is clicked, user will be able to enter information and click the `Submit` button for that particular child form, and it gets saved to the database. Same goes to `Remove`, with just clicking the `x`, it gets removed instantly.

It will be great if creating a new `Country` can also be ajaxed. But for the moment, I am using 2-step approach. First the user creates the `Country`, when click `Next`, it gets saved to the database and redirect to the edit page. In the view of the edit page, it checks if `.new_record?`, then shows the rest of the child forms.

For your advice, you may refer solely from the code from the link given above. That alone is sufficed. Your help is greatly, greatly appreciated as I have stumbled on this for weeks.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to think about. If you are doing this with RESTful actions (default), when user clicks "Add", it will have to send a method => :post. But when user click "X", it will have to send a method => :delete. And of course a normal select shop C will be a method => :get. Since the http method is attached to the form, you'll have to dynamically switch that--in Javascript? Unless you can overwrite the default rest verbs in the routes files.

Similarly, adding, fetching, and deleting allnormally use differnet methods on the controller, so you will have to hand calling those.

What this seems to mean it that you should abandon any use of a form or select tag, and simply build an ajaxy list, with your add and delete links appropriately added and styled.